# Should I remove the Windows update 2982791?

Tags: windows-7, windows-update

My Windows 7 PC has just notified me that there is a windows update available (2993651).

I also read, in the link below, that:

> The security bulletin says that "Microsoft strongly recommends that customers who have not uninstalled the 2982791 update [i.e., the old version, released on Patch Tuesday] do so prior to applying the 2993651 update [the new version]." This recommendation applies to users whether they are having problems with the old update or not. Note that Windows Update and Automatic Updates do not remove the old version.

In my “installed updates” I seem to have 2982791 installed. Should I remove it and always read the bulletins for Windows 7 from Microsoft?

Comment: You should probably change the title to "Should I remove the Windows update 2982791", based on how the question is formed.

Comment: Yes, the current title "Removing Windows updates" suggests you're asking *how* to, not *whether* to. I've suggested an edit which should fix this.

Comment: If MS suggests not to install it, then don't install it or if you have, uninstall it. Doesn't get any more complex than that